# reactjs, how to make a component that can take props and a child

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a hook component with an API like this

```js
<CopyToClipboard
    text={thetext}
    onCopy={oncpied}>
    <button className="button">Copy</button>
</CopyToClipboard>
```

This is my take

```js
const CopyToClipBoard = ({ text, onCopy }) => {
    const docopy = async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
            onCopy()
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to copy: ', err)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
export default CopyToClipBoard
```

But I got some error with the children

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to get `children` from prop object

```
const CopyToClipBoard = ({ text, onCopy, children }) => {
    const docopy = async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
            onCopy()
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to copy: ', err)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
export default CopyToClipBoard
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't destructured children from props before using it and hence the error

```
const CopyToClipBoard = ({ text, onCopy, children }) => {
    const docopy = async () => {
        try {
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
            onCopy()
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Failed to copy: ', err)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
            {children}
        </>
    )
}
export default CopyToClipBoard
```